# remove character on sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

| John
| Robert
| Mary
| James
| Bond

i want to remove characters with prefix 'J' with substr

| ohn
| Robert
| Mary
| ames
| Bond

this my sql code, but still not working

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name,2) FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE 'J%'
```

Comment: VERY helpful in questions if it says, "here's what I want; but here's what I got." (You are missing the "here's what I got" part.) Often, when I write my own questions, just going through that process shows me the answer -- or at least what I need to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you wrote says "show me all the names that needed to be modified", but what I think you want is, "Show me ALL the names, but names that follow a particular pattern I want you to modify first."

The job of modifying the data in the results is the responsibility of the `SELECT` statement. You've touched on it yourself with your use of `SUBSTR`. So you want to pull all the names, but only change some of them. Further study into the catalog of MySQL string operations reveals a dizzying array of options. The goal is "SELECT name but if name starts with 'J' then chop that off."

For educational purposes, I encourage you to try to implement this with `IF` logic, but ultimately that's not necessary.

And while the ultimately powerful regex functions are tempting, there's a simpler option, [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim). `TRIM` allows you to say, "chop this string from the front and/or back of this other string."

Since you want all results, there is no `WHERE` clause anymore, and your query is simply

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'J' FROM name) FROM table_name
```

Look at that. `FROM` meaning two different things. No one ever said SQL was pretty.

If your actual use-case is trickier than simple `TRIM` can handle, there's a whole bunch more functions to peruse, and ultimately there's regex.

Comment: Note that as written, THERE IS A CATCH! if name is 'JJohn', this statement will return 'ohn'. If you what 'John' in this case, then more work is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to check others forms to use TRIM function in a following link:

[TRIM Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_trim.asp#:%7E:text=The%20TRIM()%20function%20removes,()%20and%20RTRIM()%20functions.)